# A question about switch rating

Tags: switches

I have a PSU with 60A inrush current. If I use [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/cc30/0900766b8138bbbd.pdf) switch to turn ON the PSU, can it survive the 60A inrush in the long run? I cannot see such parameter is given in switch datasheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **switch** used in this FKH series power entry module is [rated](https://ch.schurter.com/de/FAQ):

> Meets switching current test acc. to UL 1054, TV-3

So that’s a 51A inrush rating 25,000 operations, and would appear to be inadequate for your application, however the series parts in the filter may sufficiently mitigate the inrush so you might want to check that out.

Comment: Could you update that link?

Comment: And where is 51A indicated?

Comment: @ty_1917 You will have to click through several menus to find the applicable data. There is no way to link directly to the page afaik. The 51A is part of the UL 1054 TV-3 rating as stated above. You can order the standard if you need to, it's not free, and I would not link to a pirated copy even if I had such  link (I don't).

Answer (score 2):

> can it survive the 60A inrush in the long run?

Inrush does not happen periodically i.e. generally it happens only when the input is applied while the input capacitors are empty. Because the empty input caps are pretty much a short circuit (i.e. close to zero Ohms) so a large current flows first then decays as the input caps charge up. So, I believe there's no such thing like "inrush during long run".

> I cannot see such parameter is given in switch datasheets

Some manufacturers provide detailed information about the components used in the module such as single/double pole contacts, illumination elements (if any), filtering components, etc. Yours does not give such details (except for filtering components) so it's hard to tell.

From my experience in the consumer electronics in the recent years, I remember that we used 16-Amp **high inrush type** double pole switches having inrush rating of 120+ Amps, and 10-Amp-rated same type ones having that rating of 70+ (or 80+) Amps. If yours was a high inrush type, these numbers would definitely be indicated somewhere in the datasheet.

It's better to speak to manufacturer about the inrush ratings, and they can suggest a different product if needed.

---

Although it's a known fact that the DC resistances of the input filter section (i.e. DCRs of L1 and L2 shown in the datasheet) help to reduce the inrush peaks and thus the inrush in the practical use will definitely be less than 60A, it's still not the thing to be relied on. So it's better to speak to the manufacturer for more reliable information.